# Equivalent file -s in AIX

Tags: aix

I need to know the file system type in `/dev/device..` in an AIX 7.I environment.

What is the equivalent `file -s` from Linux in AIX?

Comment: Is there nothing like `fstyp` on AIX?

Comment: There's no real equivalent under AIX, even less one that would provide that information to non-root users. Would be helpful if you could add some context on why you need to know that information.

Closest alternative would probably be `lsfs -q`.

Comment: `getlvcb -At` might also help although it needs to be run against the LV name, not the actual /dev path.